# How would I get this specific value in Mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to retrieve a specific value using Mongodb however I need to use the value "username" to be able to grab the "uuid" and I just need the UUID itself not the username
Here are screenshots on the code

How can I approach this?

**calling the database to return just the uuid**

[image: calling the database to return just the uuid]

**trying to grab the uuid from the database**

[image: trying to grab the uuid from the database]

**picture of the collection**

[image: picture of the collection]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266